# google-maps-react user location not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, components

I am trying to display the user location on the map using google-maps-react. I followed the fullstack tutorial, but I just can't seem to display the user location.  I will display my Map.js  Component below.  Please help me point out what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const {lat, lng} = this.props.initialCenter;
    this.state = {
      currentLocation: {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
      }
    }
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.google !== this.props.google) {
      this.loadMap();
    }
    if (prevState.currentLocation !== this.state.currentLocation) {
      this.recenterMap();
    }
  }
  recenterMap() {
    const map = this.map;
    const curr = this.state.currentLocation;

    const google = this.props.google;
    const maps = google.maps;

    if (map) {
        let center = new maps.LatLng(curr.lat, curr.lng)
        map.panTo(center)
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.centerAroundCurrentLocation) {
        if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
                const coords = pos.coords;
                this.setState({
                    currentLocation: {
                        lat: coords.latitude,
                        lng: coords.longitude
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }
    this.loadMap();
  }
  loadMap() {
    if (this.props && this.props.google) {
      // google is available
      const {google} = this.props;
      const maps = google.maps;

      const mapRef = this.refs.map;
      const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(mapRef);

      let {initialCenter, zoom} = this.props;
      const {lat, lng} = initialCenter;
      const center = new maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      const mapConfig = Object.assign({}, {
        center: center,
        zoom: zoom
      })
      this.map = new maps.Map(node, mapConfig);
    }
  }
  render() {
    const style = {
      width: '100vw',
      height: '100vh'
    }
    return (
      <div ref='map' style={style}>
        Loading map...
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Map.propTypes = {
  google: React.PropTypes.object,
  zoom: React.PropTypes.number,
  initialCenter: React.PropTypes.object,
  centerAroundCurrentLocation: React.PropTypes.bool
}
Map.defaultProps = {
  zoom: 13,
  // San Francisco, by default
  initialCenter: {
    lat: 37.774929,
    lng: -122.419416
  },
  centerAroundCurrentLocation: false
}


export default Map
```

Comment: Did you ever find out the problem?